# NSWindow not refreshing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

**Tested using a xib instead of code and works like a charm.
Still think a proper solution and cause should be found.
Will keep on updating as needed**

Making a popUp window with a NSProgressIndicator to show how a communication process is going.

The problem is that the progressIndicator won't update.

Checked and working:

- alertPopUp is key
- alertPopUp is front most
- alertPopUp receives increment call
- progressIndicator values are updated correctly
- progressIndicator in both alertPopUp and main window, main window progressIndicator bar fills

Checked and not working:

- progressIndicator bar won't fill

Noticed behaviour:

- On 3 fingers swipe up movement, displaying all available windows in system, the alertPopUp window will update once, and only once.

Tested the same code in the main app window and worked perfectly.

If i make the alertPopUp window main won't make a difference.

Ideas are really welcome, completely blocked.

Gonna show you the alertPopUp Code and the caller:

```
@implementation XTAlertPopUp{
    NSProgressIndicator *progressBar;
    double incrementStep;
}

+ (XTAlertPopUp *)_baseInit:(NSView *)caller delegate:(id<XTAlertPopUpDelegate>)delegate{
    CGRect viewPositionInScreen = [caller.window convertRectToScreen:[caller convertRect:caller.bounds toView:nil]];

    XTAlertPopUp *alertPopUp = [[XTAlertPopUp alloc] initWithContentRect:CGRectMake(viewPositionInScreen.origin.x + ((caller.frame.size.width - windowWidth) * .5), viewPositionInScreen.origin.y + ((caller.frame.size.height - windowHeight) * .5), windowWidth, windowHeight)
                                                               styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                                 backing: NSBackingStoreRetained
                                                                   defer:YES];

    alertPopUp.alertDelegate = delegate;

    return alertPopUp;
}

+ (XTAlertPopUp *)alertProgressCalledFromView:(NSView *)caller withMessage:(NSString *)msg numberOfProgressStages:(NSUInteger)progressStages andCancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelTitle settingDelegate:(id<XTAlertPopUpDelegate>)delegate{
    XTAlertPopUp *alertPopUp = [XTAlertPopUp _baseInit:caller delegate:delegate];

    NSBox *base = [alertPopUp _baseViewForAlert:msg cancelButton:cancelTitle];
    [alertPopUp _buildProgressBarAndAddTo:base numberOfProgressStages:progressStages];

    [alertPopUp setContentView:base];
    [base release];

    return alertPopUp;
}

- (void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [progressBar release];
}

#pragma mark --
#pragma mark UI
- (NSBox *)_baseViewForAlert:(NSString *)msg cancelButton:(NSString *)cancelTitle{
    NSBox *base = [[NSBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    [base setBoxType:NSBoxCustom];
    [base setFillColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [base setBorderColor:[NSColor orangeColor]];
    [base setBorderWidth:2.0];

    NSImageView *appIcon = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewBorder, viewBorder, windowHeight - (viewBorder * 2), windowHeight - (viewBorder * 2))];
    [appIcon setImage:[NSApp applicationIconImage]];
    [base addSubview:appIcon];

    NSTextField *text = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(appIcon.frame.origin.x + appIcon.frame.size.width + viewBorder, (viewBorder * 2) + buttonSizeHeight, base.frame.size.width - (appIcon.frame.origin.x + appIcon.frame.size.width + (viewBorder * 3)), base.frame.size.height - ((viewBorder * 4) + buttonSizeHeight))];
    [text.cell setStringValue:msg];
    [text.cell setWraps:YES];
    [text setEditable:NO];
    [text setSelectable:NO];
    [text.cell setBordered:NO];
    [text.cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [text setTextColor:[NSColor orangeColor]];
    [base addSubview:text];

    [base addSubview:[[self configureButton:CGRectMake(viewBorder, viewBorder, buttonsSizeWidth, buttonSizeHeight)
                                            title:cancelTitle
                                              tag:0] autorelease]];

    [text release];
    [appIcon release];

    return base;
}

- (void)_buildProgressBarAndAddTo:(NSBox *)base numberOfProgressStages:(NSUInteger)progressStages{
    progressBar = [[NSProgressIndicator alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewBorder + (windowHeight - (viewBorder * 2)), viewBorder, base.frame.size.width -  ((viewBorder * 2) + (windowHeight - (viewBorder * 2))), 50)];
    [progressBar setIndeterminate:NO];
    [progressBar setMinValue:0.0];
    [progressBar setMaxValue:100.0];
    [progressBar setDoubleValue:0.0];
    [progressBar setStyle:NSProgressIndicatorBarStyle];
    [progressBar setControlSize:NSRegularControlSize];
    [progressBar setControlTint:NSGraphiteControlTint];
    [progressBar setDisplayedWhenStopped:YES];

    [base addSubview:progressBar];

    incrementStep = 100.0 / progressStages;
}

- (NSButton *)configureButton:(CGRect)frame title:(NSString *)title tag:(NSUInteger)tag{
    NSButton *btn = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [btn setTag:tag];
    [btn setCell:[[[XTColorFrameButtonCell alloc] init] autorelease]];
    [btn.cell setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
    [btn setBordered:YES];
    [btn.cell setBordered:YES];
    [btn setState:NO];
    [[btn cell] setTitle:title];
    [btn.cell setAction:@selector(buttonClicked:)];

    [btn.cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    [btn.cell setFrameColor:[NSColor orangeColor]];
    [btn.cell setButtonToPatchParams];

    return btn;
}

- (void)incrementProgress{
    if([progressBar doubleValue] >= 100.0)
        [self killAlert];
    [progressBar incrementBy:incrementStep];
    NSLog(@"double >> %f", [progressBar doubleValue]);
    NSLog(@"iskey >> %d || ismain >> %d", [self isKeyWindow], [self isMainWindow]);
    [progressBar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

#pragma mark --
#pragma mark window override
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow{
    return YES;
}
```

You can use this to call for testing:

```
- (void)testprogressBar{
    [self alertPopUpSaveProgress:@(100)];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(increments:) userInfo:@(0) repeats:NO];
}

- (void)increments:(NSTimer *)timer{

    NSNumber *inc = @([[timer userInfo] integerValue] + 1);
    if([inc integerValue] > 99)
        return;
    NSLog(@"patch iskey >> %d || patch is main >> %d", [self.view.window isKeyWindow], [self.view.window isMainWindow]);
    [alertProgress incrementProgress];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(increments:) userInfo:inc repeats:NO];
}

- (void)alertPopUpSaveProgress:(NSNumber *)numberOfSteps{
    alertProgress = [XTAlertPopUp alertProgressCalledFromView:self.view
                                                        withMessage:@"Saving changes"
                                             numberOfProgressStages:[numberOfSteps unsignedIntegerValue]
                                               andCancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                                    settingDelegate:self];
    [alertProgress shootThreadedAlert];
}
```

Comment: the UI is always on the main thread so if you block that with any long running task it won't update.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I'm aware of that, and in this code the main thread isn't blocked, no heavy task is running on it and all other UI are updated correctly. Tested using a new approach, NSWindowController+XIB, it worked perfectly... If what your saying is the reason shouldn't this new approach fail, shouldn't the other windows fail to update?